# Pytest Tkinter Messagebox

Tags: python-3.x, testing, tkinter, pytest, tkmessagebox

My program generates an Alert / Message Box using the code below.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
messagebox.showwarning('End of Data', "You have reached the end of the data.")
```

I want to run a simple unit test on this code. I want to assert that the message box appears and that the text in the message box is "You have reached the end of the data.". Perhaps something like `assert appears` and `assert message == "You have reached the end of the data."`.

Ideally I'd like to do this using PyTest, however solutions using other frameworks would still be greatly appreciated.

(For context I am using Python 3.)

Comment: Maybe the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50482707/testing-tkinter-application/50488952#50488952) can help.

Comment: Thanks, I believe I looked at that answer previously and may have ignored it for being too complicated. The test that I was running was kind of the icing on the cake and my deadline was very close (and has since passed). Hence if I couldn't do it simply I wasn't going to do it at all. When I have time I might look at that answer in more detail and see if I can tailor it to my situation.

Comment: That solution may also answer another issue I encountered. The warning above is contained within a next() method that moves a graph along an axis, but if you try to go too far the message appears and the graph does not move. I was able to write a unit test for next(), including an assertion that checked that the data does not move when it hits the "end zone". However the appearance of the messagebox disrupted the rest of the unit tests, so I just removed this endzone test. If there's a way to close the messagebox as part of the test that would kill 2 birds with one stone.